# Using same font for \texttt and \Verb

Tags: fontsize, typewriter, fancyvrb

I would like to configure my document to use exactly the same font for `\texttt` and `\Verb`. I got as far as this, which still misses making `\ttdefault` smaller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\fvset{fontfamily=fvm}
\fvset{fontsize=\relsize{-2}}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm} % needs to be smaller...
\begin{document}

$\langle$ \Verb!foobar123! $\rangle$

$\langle \texttt{foobar123} \rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

So how to I apply the `relsize{-2}` by default to `\texttt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using low level `\fontsize` and `\fontfamily` commands or `\relsize`, you should load the package `beramono` that provides a `scaled` option for deciding the height of the characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.75]{beramono}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

Some text $\langle$\Verb!foobar123!$\rangle$ end.

Some text $\langle\texttt{foobar123}\rangle$ end.

\end{document}
```

Change the fraction `.75` to what really suits you. In any case, since `\texttt` and `\Verb` by default use the same font, this will ensure the same result in both cases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this font was `beramono`, but indeed it looks the same. I use it with `scaled=0.73` and a baseline stretch of `0.95` which gives me approximately the same line spacing as before, so I don't have to go over the layout of >100 pages again.