# How to write a sentence full of symbols

Tags: symbols, environments

I just started using LaTeX and I have a problem including this in my file:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

is there some kind of a "de-specialized" environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you perhaps looking for `\verb|X5O!P%@AP[4\PZ...$H+H*|`?

Comment: Thank you ! it works too but the font has changed, is there a way to keep the same font ?

Comment: Would this be relevant? "[Change typeface of verbatim environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120633/46980)" See also: "[Using same font for \texttt and \Verb](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101680/46980)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `listings` package to include literal content.  The vertical bar `|` after `\lstinline` is the delimiter of the literal content.  It mustn't appear among the characters in your string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline|X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*|
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

You have many special symbols in your line of text. These special symbols mean something in LaTeX like any other programming language. So, you should take care when writing these symbols, e.g., `\` precedes macros in LaTeX, `$` means begin math mode, `{`,`}` are used to group expressions, etc.

There is also the `\verb| ... |` macro or its environment `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` if you don't mind using the `typewriter` typeface.

Also, you can add

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont}
\makeatother
```

and use the same font within `\verb` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

X5O!P\%@AP[4\textbackslash PZX54(P\textasciicircum)7CC)7\}\$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!\$H+H*

\verb|X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\@` surely does not produce `@`.

Comment: that's true I just noticed, what to do to include @ ?

Comment: Just type `@`.  It's that easy.

Answer (score 4):

Package `url`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\despecialized{\urlstyle{same}}
\begin{document}
\despecialized|X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]